# Propylene Glycol Degradation due to Sunlight

Tags: aromatic-compounds

I had a translucent container of propylene glycol exposed to sunlight.  When I went to use it, I noticed it has a strong "acetone" like odor.  Someone said it was a photo-oxidation reaction of the glycol into ketones or aldehydes.  What happened and will the odor get worse even though it is is now removed from sunlight?  Do I need to worry about these ketones or aldehydes in the glycol?

Answer (score 3):

The thermal degradation of propylene glycol and its uses in e-cigarettes has been a discussed in a [previous question here on Chem.SE.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14771/how-does-propylene-glycol-glycerin-form-formaldehyde-acetaldehyde-when-vaporized)

> Upon complete oxidation and degradation, propylene glycol will fully
>   decompose to carbon dioxide and oxygen. However, if there is partial
>   oxidation, you will get some intermediate species - formaldehyde or
>   acetaldehyde.(1st answer)
>
> Propylene glycol does not decompose on heating, it simply boils. In
>   theory, under certain conditions (pressure/encapsulation/catalysts) it
>   could dehydrate to either acetone or Propionaldehyde, probably the
>   former.(2nd answer)

Also, [this link](https://dowac.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5280) shows the decomposition products of propylene glycol which are all acid based:

> The main degradation product of propylene glycol was lactic acid (2-hydroxypropionic
>   acid), with formic, acetic, and oxalic acids as minor products.

So, mainly degradation of propylene glycol in sunlight would yield a bunch of acids and small amounts of acetone. Worrying about the odors is a personal medical question and is off-topic in Chem.SE.