# Can glycerine be degraded by UV light?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I would like to know, if UV degradation of glycerine is possible and what is the reaction mechanism? It is explicitly about glycerine and I could not find anything useful in the literature.

Comment: Like any organic compound can be, but I don't think it's particularly relevant to this one.

Comment: Simple alcohols and hydrocarbons have no electronic transitions in the common instrument ultraviolet above ~190-210 nm. Unless you have access to the vacuum uv  any degradation or reaction would be from photoinitiation from impurities present that absorbed the uv light available. Run a uv spectrum and let us know. It seems that Sigma Aldrich has discontinued their spectra grade glycerin so you will have to search round or purify some. [do not ask me how; it seems to be one of those compounds with a good melting point but does not refreeze; I was going to suggest zone refining!]

Comment: Yes, glycerine can be degraded by UV light. When glycerine is exposed to UV light, it breaks down into smaller molecules that are then more easily broken down by other means.

Comment: Related propylene glycol: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75988/propylene-glycol-degradation-due-to-sunlight?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: While some may have a difference in opinion, but per a source, "Darker colors absorb more UV than lighter colors like whites and pastels. This means the UV rays are less likely to reach your skin. But bright colors such as red can also absorb UV rays. The more vivid the color, the greater the protection—a bright yellow shirt is more protective than a pale one."  http://depts.washington.edu/cmditr/modules/lum/color.html . So, adding say Vitamin B12, could promote a photolysis, as I have actually performed.